# Ubuntu 16.04 laptop fan running very modestly

Tags: drivers, 16.04, fan

I am currently running Ubuntu 16.04 kernel 4.6 and my laptop fan does not work as expected. It stays at 0 RPM until my temps reach around 85C, and even after that it runs at 2500 RPM which is the minimum speed my fan runs at.

The problem did not exist when i was previously at 15.04 and the fan used to work properly. I even tried using fan control but it did not work as per my needs

How do i fix this

Comment: Laptop model and make?

Comment: its a Dell inspiron 15R 5521 , bios version A14

Comment: What happens when you switch kernels (ie: use the 4.4 kernel that came with 16.04)?

Comment: i was on 4.4 only earlier, same problem. I updated the kernel hoping that it would fix it but it didn't.

Comment: Try booting a LiveCD, see if the fan speed is any different while running up the CPU. In addition, the fact that `fancontrol` worked for you is actually pretty great. See the manpage for params to configure: https://linux.die.net/man/8/fancontrol. Finally, delve into your BIOS and check to see if there are any issues regarding the fan.

Comment: from a LiveCd or even before performing the system updates , the fan used to run at max 5100 all the time. Which was also not desirable.And `fancontrol` didn't work properly for me as such, it just used to keep my fan at 0 RPM with random quarter second bursts to max 5100 RPM